# Bootstrap hamburger menu will not open,

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked at everything on Bootstrap's hamburger menu, none of the answers have worked for me. I think I could have a syntax error but the console is not saying there are any errors and I know my jQuery and JavaScript are linked properly. Please take a look and let me know what I should change, here is my code:

```html
<nav class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a href="index.html">Google Fiber to Louisville</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="index-header">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="index-header">
      <ul class="nav navbar-left">
        <li id="form-tab"class="nav navbar-right"><a href="#">Add your name!</a></li>
        <li id="supporters-tab"class="navbar-right"><a href="#">Supporters</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the # to identify the ID on your `data-target="index-header"`, should be `data-target="#index-header"` See [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Also (just in case) make sure you have all your dependencies in place:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery followed by BootstrapJS See [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Working example Snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#index-header" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Google Fiber to Louisville</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="index-header">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li id="form-tab" class="nav navbar-right"><a href="#">Add your name!</a>
        </li>
        <li id="supporters-tab" class="navbar-right"><a href="#">Supporters</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your button html with is

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#index-header">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

You missing/not proper `class="collapsed"` and `data-target="#index-header"`